# $[N_G(H), H] = H \Rightarrow N_G(H) = H$?

Tags: group-theory

For a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$, is the following statement true?

If $[N_G(H), H] = H$, then $N_G(H) = H$

(where $[N_G(H), H]$ is the group generated by $\{[x, y] = xyx^{-1}y^{-1} \mid x \in N_G(H), y \in H \}$).

If it is true, how to prove it? Thanks.

Comment: Why would it? Note that $[N_G(H),H]\leq H$ for all $H$, and always contains $[H,H]$. So just take any group with $[H,H]=H$, and any nontrivial group $K$. Then $H\triangleleft H\times K=G$, so $N_G(H)=G\neq H$, but $[N_G(H),H]=H$ holds.

Answer (score 3):

$G = S_3$, $H = \langle (123)\rangle$, then $H\lhd G$ and so $N_G(H) = G$. We have
\begin{equation*}
[N_G(H),H] = \langle xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\mid x\in N_G(H),y\in H\rangle = H
\end{equation*}
because all $xyx^{-1}$'s are of order $3$ and $xyx^{-1} = y^{-1}$ for some $x,y$. But $N_G(H)\ne H$ in this case.